# How to upload a native scala project to local repo by sbt like using "maven install"

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm learning akka by reading *Learning Akka* .The package manager recommended is sbt, but I have a problem with it.

I write a project,a key:value nosql memory database server demo, whose package manager is sbt and its build.sbt is as follwing:

```
name := "akkademy-db-scala"

organization := "com.akkademy-db"

version := "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-agent" % "2.3.6",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.6",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.3.6",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-testkit" % "2.3.6" % "test",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.1.6" % "test"
)

mappings in (Compile, packageBin) ~= { _.filterNot { case (_, name) =>
  Seq("application.conf").contains(name)
}}
```

And then I write another project, a database client demo, whitch referencd the project above, and its build.sbt is as following:

```
name := """akkademy-db-client-scala"""

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.12"

// Change this to another test framework if you prefer
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.akkademy-db"   %% "akkademy-db-scala" % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT",
  "org.scalatest" %% "scalatest" % "2.2.4" % "test"
)
```

Here,   `"com.akkademy-db"   %% "akkademy-db-scala" % "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"` point at that projcet, but something wrong happend when the project being imported to IDEA.

```
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last update' for the full output
[error] stack trace is suppressed; run 'last ssExtractDependencies' for the full output
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.akkademy-db:akkademy-db-scala_2.11:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\yxmak\.ivy2\localcom.akkademy-db\akkademy-db-scala_2.11\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/akkademy-db/akkademy-db-scala_2.11/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/akkademy-db-scala_2.11-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[error] (ssExtractDependencies) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: Error downloading com.akkademy-db:akkademy-db-scala_2.11:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[error]   Not found
[error]   Not found
[error]   not found: C:\Users\yxmak\.ivy2\localcom.akkademy-db\akkademy-db-scala_2.11\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT\ivys\ivy.xml
[error]   not found: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/akkademy-db/akkademy-db-scala_2.11/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/akkademy-db-scala_2.11-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
```

It seems that sbt can't found the referenced project in local library.

How should I upload my project to local libarary by sbt? In maven, it is "maven install", and other maven project can reference the installed jar. Is there any way to "install" my scala project managed by sbt?

Comment: Scala 2.11 and akka 2.3 are super old and have no support. If you are going to start a new project I suggest to consider to upgrade to the latest version

Comment: What you are looking for, is how to [publish locally in sbt](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Publishing.html#Publishing+locally). It can be done with `sbt publishLocal`

Comment: @GastónSchabas Thanks, it works. Thanks for your help to a beginner.